# how to resolve Salesforce select query error in mule?

Tags: salesforce, mule, soql

I'm executing below query on SFA from mule batch processing face.

```
SELECT id, EmailADD 
FROM Contact WHERE Email = '#[dw('payload.Emailadd')]'
```

it is working fine for 4000-5000 records, When 50000 records come it throws below error:

> Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was:
>   Invalid token at 1:54. Type: class
>   org.mule.common.query.dsql.parser.exception.DsqlParsingException
>
> Message               : Broken pipe (java.net.SocketException) Element
>   : null
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------Exception stack is:Broken pipe (java.net.SocketException)
>   (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException) (set debug level logging or
>   '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Answer (score 0):

Put a limit in your query and check.

```
Integer maxQueryRows = Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows();

SELECT id, EmailADD 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Email = '#[dw('payload.Emailadd')]' 
LIMIT maxQueryRows
```